# Deleting expired PHP session files on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

Everything started with MySQL not being able to start.

After some web searching I found out that the server ran out of inodes.

`df -i`

```
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/simfs     500000 500000      0  100% /
none           131072     56 131016    1% /dev
none           131072      1 131071    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           131072     63 131009    1% /run
none           131072      4 131068    1% /run/lock
none           131072      1 131071    1% /run/shm
none           131072      1 131071    1% /run/user
```

Further googling led me to the assumption that the PHP session files never get deleted... which seem to be true because running `ls php5 | wc -l` gives me `424669`!

I read that the PHP.ini session.gc_probability is set to 0 by default and that ubuntu handles the cleanup through the cronjob `/etc/cron.d/php5.`

**/etc/cron.d/php5**

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

#Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)
```

This looks right, so why isn't this script working? Is there a way for me to confirm that this is actually run every 30 minutes?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865303/debian-based-systems-session-killed-at-30-minutes-in-special-cron-how-to-overri
But your problem is very rare. Check your permissions (for www-data user) from save_path directive (if www-data user not have permissions, not delete sessions).

Comment: But the cron is run by the root user so it should be that I need to check permissions for the www-data user?

`drwx-wx-wt  3 root      root     24M Feb  6 15:04 php5`

Answer (score 1):

> PHP session files never get deleted

You don't say what session handler you are using - assuming its the default, expired sessions should be cleaned out whenever session garbage collection is triggered. 
You've got session.cache_expire too high and/or session.gc_probability too low, and/or session.gc_divisor too high.

> session.gc_probability is set to 0 by default

No - only on Debian systems (Ubuntu is derived from Debian). Someone at Debian [thinks having strange permissions](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=267720) on the sessions storage prevents sessions hi-jacking. Actually it only deals with a *very* narrow subset of possible attacks - and when you put in appropriate measures to deal with the more likely attack vectors, the problem goes away.

A consequence of this is that you need root access if you want to manage your PHP sessions in any way other than that which has been pre-determined by Debian.

Mostly I like Debian - but this always struck me as rather silly.

Answer (score 0):

You could write to syslog using the Logger command since your running it as Root.

**&& logger -t PHP_SESSIONS "PHP Sessions cleared"**

then "**cat /var/log/syslog | grep PHP_SESSIONS**" later on to see the times that it ran.

Of course that just tells you the cron job ran and not if it was successful.